# Which sizes should I deliver icons in? (Desktop, not web)

Tags: icon, export, mac, windows

It's the first time I am designing some icons for use on a desktop, but I have now come to the point where I have to export them as `.ico`.

My question: How do I deliver, hand in the icons to the customer? I have no trouble exporting to `.ico`, but what sizes should I deliver? Do OSs resize automatically and should I just deliver a 512*512 or 256*256 version, or should I resize in different steps and export for every size?

Comment: you might want to check out this Q at StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236115/which-icon-sizes-should-my-windows-applications-icon-include

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but an .ico file can store multiple resolutions.  There are several online generators that will create an. ico file from an uploaded .png and embed the different sizes into one file for you.

Comment: The whole point of ico files is embedding a range of resolutions appropriate for the destination. Sketch has a built in template for OSX icons. You'd have to export then generate your ico.

Comment: See [this answer at StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10819673/6424399): It tells you the exact sizes and how to do it with GIMP.

Answer (score 1):

In the limited experience I have with supplying icons for desktop apps, I was asked to submit `*.ico` files with multiple embedded resolution, from ldpi to xxxhdpi.